# What's the difference between now() and time() in Python?

Tags: python

I´d like to know the difference between those two functions in Python, time.now() and time.time().
Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are at least two different definitions of `time()` in the standard libraries. Which one are you talking about? `datetime.time()` or `time.time()` or another one?

Comment: Which version of python has `time.now()`? I don't see it in the documentation for 2.x or 3.x.

Comment: @Kevin: my guess is that she's referring not to the *functions* `now` and `time` but to the two *methods* of `datetime` objects.  I.e. her "time" is a datetime instance, not the module.

Comment: Hi @DSM could you explain that a little better? I'm new in this Python thing so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: do you have a piece of code showing your use of the two functions? We can then analyze what objects or classes you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `datetime.now()` and `time.time()` :

`datetime.now()` will be more precise, if possible.

See:

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Comment: I meant time.time() and time.now()

Comment: There is no `time.now()` according to a raised exception.

Comment: I´m using now() after the imports:  "from time import time
from time import sleep"